# Azure AD with Bearer token authentication for Web API not working throwing error as "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication, api-authorization

A noob question on the way.

I have developed Azure Ad authentication for a Web APi using the example from Git site [https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof/tree/master/TodoListService]
I have been facing an issue with Azure Ad authentication.
Please find the code below.

Action method from Controller1 class.

```
   [RoutePrefix("api/hospitals")]
   public class HospitalsController : ApiController
   {
    [Route("GetAll")]
    [HttpGet]
    [PmAuthorize(Constants.Roles.Admin,Constants.Roles.Doctor)]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<hospitals>> GetAll()
    { 
      //return data;....
    }
    }
```

My startup.auth.cs file

```
    public partial class Startup
    {
    string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

    string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

    static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

    string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);
     public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
           new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
           {
               Tenant = tenant,
               TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { SaveSigninToken = true, ValidAudience = "clientid" }
           });
    }
  }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
  {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Filters.Add(new ExceptionHandlingAttribute());
        }
       }
```

When ever i am calling a action method/api method call from hospital controller by passing token getting the error as "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Can some one help me here ?.

Please add any comments if any addition info required ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make a custom attribute or is `PmAuthorize` a typo?

Comment: @Crowcoder inside PmAuthorize we are inheriting Authorize attribute for roles

Comment: Have you provided the required permission and consented them? can you  please provide correlation id and timestamp

Comment: Are you still looking for any help with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a blunder mistake from my side.

I had to add a few lines of code inside the "PmAuthorize" attribute to give roles for the user.

That gave me answer.